# Spring Data JPA + JPQL with @CollectionTable/@ElementCollection - Conditional Search by Collection of Enums

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have an `Entity` with such `Enum -> String` `@CollectionTable`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "place")
public class Place {

    //....

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @CollectionTable(name = "general_place_type", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "place_id"))
    @Column(name = "place_type")
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<GeneralPlaceType> types;

    //....
}
```

Also I have following queried method in my Spring Data Repository:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Place p WHERE ...... AND :type MEMBER OF p.types AND ......")
Page<Place> getAllByGeneralSingleType(@Param("type") GeneralPlaceType type, Pageable pageable);

//Conditions non-related to question topic are marked with dots
```

Actually, it works well and does its job - finding all Places which types contain incoming type.

I'm thinking of making similar(?) method to aggregate places with one key condition for search results: each of them should contain ***at least one*** type from incoming `Collection` of `GeneralPlaceType`:

```
//It might look like this
Page<Place> getAllByGeneralMultipleTypes(@Param("types") Set<GeneralPlaceType>, Pageable pageable);
```

How can I achieve that functionality with JPQL `@Query` or even maybe with pure Spring Data Repository Methods?

Comment: Ummm... `JOIN p.types type WHERE type IN :types`?

Comment: `JOIN` indeed seems to work well. I was thinking of excessive solutions, but answer was quite simple. Thanks!